# How can i drag&drop without array?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

I made a program to display the contents of json files with drag&drop in Text Box.

```
private void TextBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

        TextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(files[0]);
    }
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307966/how-to-provide-file-drag-and-drop-functionality-in-a-visual-c-applicat

I created a drag&drop function on this site.

But I don't want to use array because I want to bring only one file. But I couldn't find it.

How can I load the contents of a file with drag&drop without array?

Comment: Don't rely solely on one article look around a bit. For example i found this: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2019/09/let-the-user-drag-listbox-items-in-c/

Comment: But what you're doing now (taking the first item out of the array) is a good solution - so whats wrong with what you're doing now? why should it be changed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to limit the number of files been dragged and dropped. You can show an error if there are multiple files.

```
void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    if (files.Length == 1)
    {
        TextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(files[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        // Show an error
    }
}
```